# Spring Data Redis deletes entries (hashes), but leaves indices

Tags: redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

When using Spring Data with Redis I'm encountering situation that it's providing empty objects on `#findAll` invocation.

When `#deleteAll` is called on the entity sometimes `:idx` keys are not deleted.

For me it looks like Spring Data is using secondary indices for `#findAll` and cannot get object as it has already been deleted in Redis.

We've found out that `@EnableRedisRepositories(enableKeyspaceEvents = RedisKeyValueAdapter.EnableKeyspaceEvents.ON_STARTUP)` could help, but I would like to ask you if you could explain what is going on and provide any other solution as I'm not so experienced with Redis.

When doing delete directly in Redis, there is the same situation. Looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
 1) "entry:key:testKey3"
 2) "entry:1234_testKey1"
 3) "entry:eid:1234"
 4) "entry"
 5) "entry:1234_testKey3"
 6) "entry:1234_testKey1:idx"
 7) "entry:key:testKey2"
 8) "entry:1234_testKey2:idx"
 9) "entry:1234_testKey2"
10) "entry:key:testKey1"
11) "entry:1234_testKey3:idx"
127.0.0.1:6379> del entry:1234_testKey1
(integer) 1
```

And, as you can see `entry:1234_testKey1:idx` index has not been deleted.

```
 1) "entry:key:testKey3"
 2) "entry:eid:1234"
 3) "entry"
 4) "entry:1234_testKey3"
 5) "entry:1234_testKey1:idx"
 6) "entry:key:testKey2"
 7) "entry:1234_testKey2:idx"
 8) "entry:1234_testKey2"
 9) "entry:key:testKey1"
10) "entry:1234_testKey3:idx"
```

Maybe there is some kind of setting in redis that I can set to cleanup indices when deleting entry? I could not find any information about that.

Entity class looks like this:

```
@RedisHash("entry")
public class Entry {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @Indexed
    private String key;
    @Indexed
    private String eid;
```

And we just use `#save`, `#deleteAll`, `#deleteById` on `CrudRepository`.

Comment: Just a suggestion. Try to delete data from redis using redis cli. If keys exists after deleteion then it is an issues otherwise please paste your code here.

Comment: It happens also directly in redis, but I still do not know why. Maybe there is some kind of setting in redis that I can set to cleanup indices when deleting entry? I could not find any information about that.

Comment: Please add the snippet here.

Comment: @MicD Were you able to figure this out? The answer given only tests this with redis. I am guessing however there is some other setting in Spring Data Redis which is doing this. Do you happen to know how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: I haven't found good solution for this. Tried with redis config to automatically remove orphans, but it didn't work as expected. Simple non null filtering was fixing the issue. Not perfect and I'm not so much satisfied, but works.

Comment: [denizdurmus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1171198) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66595713) saying "Encountered the same issue, and it seems like it is a reported issue on spring-data https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/issues/1537"

Answer (score 0):

I have tested on my cli please look at the result below:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SET test1 redis
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> SET test2 redis
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "test2"
2) "test1"
3) "PawanTest"
4) "test"
127.0.0.1:6379> DEL test1
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "test2"
2) "PawanTest"
3) "test"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

As you can see, I've added some data to redis and then deleted one key using `DEL` command and it has been deleted.

**PS:** I have not done any configuration on my system for redis. Just installed using `sudo apt-get install redis-server` and it's working fine.

**Note:** If it not working then you can try using `FLUSHALL` to clean all your datasets then some data then try again.

Comment: Thank you for your tests! I think my scenario is a bit different as I create redis hash with indices, which is done by spring-data. Hash is deleted correctly, but the index `:idx` entry is not deleted together with the hash.